# .animate() not working properly in chrome

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser

```
$( "#container_main" ).animate({ "left": "+=100%" }, "medium" );
```

This is working fine in firefox but not working properly in chrome. How i can check the cross browser compatibility in .animate() class?

Comment: depending on your direction try left: 100% or -100%

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/w7Pyu/ are you remembering to position `#container_main` ?

Comment: try left without double quotes 
$( "#container_main" ).animate({ left: "+=100%" }, "medium" );